# How to fill an AlertDialog with a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog, fullscreen, fill

I have a fullscreen AlertDialog that loads a html file in a webview. I want the html content to fill the AlertDialog, hence the screen (no problem if it has borders, although it would be nice if it doesn't).

The AlertDialog correctly fills the screen, but the webview only appears in the top of the screen, with a lot of space below. Strangely, the webview fills the width, but not the height. Look:

[image]

How can I force the webview to fill the AlertDialog?

This is my code:

```
WebView myMsg = new WebView(context);
myMsg.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(js);
myMsg.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(overflow);
myMsg.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(overflow);
myMsg.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
myMsg.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
myMsg.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myMsg.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
myMsg.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myMsg.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
myMsg.setInitialScale(1);
myMsg.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    // Prevents exposing the URI in API>26 !
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }   
});
myMsg.loadUrl(page);
myMsg.setBackgroundColor(0);
myMsg.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(myMsg)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

Window dialogWin = dialog.getWindow();
dialog.show();

if (dialogWin != null) {
    dialogWin.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialogWin.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dialogWin.setFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: A fullscreen AlertDialog isn't really meant to be a thing.  You might get better results not doing that and writing your own layout to get what you want.  You could be able to get something that works, but it would be fragile-  since it isn't an intended use case Google could break it at any time with implementation tweaks to AlertDialog.

Comment: MMmm... interesting. Do you suggest to build a full activity just for this?

Comment: Or a fragment.  Part of the problem is that Dialog assumes its a pop up on top of an Activity with a border around it, and a transparent area on all 4 sides showing the activity underneath.  Hard to get real fullscreen out of that.  It actually has a maximum size for content in order to achieve that.

Comment: Got it. I created a specific activity with just a webview implementing my code above. Works perfectly. Thanks!!